# What are good Java coding practices to help Java GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I avoid garbage collection delays in Java games? (Best Practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484079/how-can-i-avoid-garbage-collection-delays-in-java-games-best-practices)

Java's GC pause is a killer. Often the time, the application doesn't have the memory leak. At some point, it may pause for ~1 second for every 1G memory allocation.

What are good Java coding practices to help Java GC?

One example, since null object becomes eligible for garbage collection, so it is a good idea to explicitly set an object to null e.g. object = null.

Comment: "Null object"?  I don't think that's a thing...

Comment: @HighCore You realize that C# is also a garbage collected language, right?

Comment: One approach is to avoid unnecessary garbage: avoid dynamic creation of objects and use pools of reusable objects.

Comment: What I mean is set an object null to help GC collect it. For example, an application creates a context object for a user request (Tomcat/JBoss). If set context object to null, does it help Java GC and make it more efficient?

Comment: @KyleM the difference is that .Net actually works =)

Comment: @stones333 Yes setting it to null would make it eligible for garbage collection, as long as there are no other references to that object.

Comment: @HighCore I've never had problems with Java's garbage collection, or with C# garbage collection. I view complaints by those who have as their own problems of poor memory management...It's also possible to request garbage collection System.gc() or something like that. Potentially, you could do so when you know your program won't be especially busy.

Answer (score 4):

In general to help GC you should avoid of unreasonable memory usage. Simple advices could be:

1) Do not produce new objects, where it is not needed. For example do not use constructions like `String test = new String("blabla");`. If it possible, reuse old objects (it belongs to immutable objects mainly).

2) Do not declare fields in classes, where they are used only inside methods; i.e. make them local variables.

3) Avoid of using object wrappers under primitive types. I.e. use `int` instead of `Integer`, `boolean` instead of `Boolean`, if you really do not need to store in them `null` values. Also for example, where it is possible, for memory economy, do not use `ArrayList`, use simple Java `arrays` of primitive types (not `Integer[]`, but `int[]`).

Comment: Yes, that is good. What else? One more thing I can think of is to use StringBuilder.append() instead of String concatenation to avoid creating unnecessary objects.

Comment: String concatenation uses StringBuilder.append(). Disassemble some code with javap -c and see for yourself.

Comment: @DavidConrad really? Hm, in JSL7 said, that when you concatenate two strings - you produce new `String` object.

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes, when you concatenate two strings, you produce a new string object. By constructing a StringBuilder, calling its append method with each of the strings, and then calling its toString method to get the resulting string. As I said, write a trivial program, compile it, and then disassemble it with `javap -c` and you will see that even though you did not mention StringBuilder in your source code, the java compiler still emits code that uses a StringBuilder to concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 3):

The single best thing that you can do to minimize GC pauses is to properly size your heap.

If you know that your program never uses more than 1Gb of live objects, then it's pointless to pass `-Xms4096m`. That will actually *increase* your GC pauses, because the JVM will leave garbage around until it absolutely has to clear it.

Similarly, if you know that you have very few long-lived objects, you can *usually* benefit by increasing the size of the young generation relative to the tenured generation (for Sun JVMs).

The only thing that you can really do, coding-wise, is to move large objects off-heap. But that's unlikely to be useful for most applications.

Comment: Understood. As a JBoss web application, we can not dictator how users behavior. The requests could be large in size or come in faster rate .  Here is one real life example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530045/useconcmarksweepgc-strange-happening)

Answer (score 0):

Objects that are allocated and not immediately released get moved into the tenured heap space. Tenured memory is the most expensive to collect. Avoid churning through long lived objects should help with GC pauses.